# Ubuntu 18.04 freeze on Asus x640l

Tags: 18.04, asus, freeze

I am having a serious issue and need your help.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on my Asus x540l laptop, it can boot correctly but after a few time it just freezes completely at random times.

How can I fix this? I tried setting pcie_aspm=off in grub but did not help.

Comment: This is happening to me too, have you found any solution?

Comment: @thedouglenz Actually no, I bought a new laptop because WiFi adapter was having a lot of issues in my old laptop, maybe this is the problem, I will try to fix WiFi adapter to check if this will solve the problem.